# API to discover noteworthy tourist destinations in a city with summaries

Tags: api, foursquare, google-places-api, geo

I am looking for an API that will enumerate the top 30 - 50 tourist attractions for a city in the US. For each attraction, I need categorization (Museum, Landmark, ...) a picture, a two - three line summary about it, some form of rating and a link to more information.

I'd prefer a free source but am open to paid options.I've looked around and haven't found anything just yet.

The closest I could find is Google Places where the premium data option promises to be interesting except that it requires special approval to get a summary for a place - and I haven't head from the Google team in over a month. This is the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/premiumdata

Foursquare has venues but I've ruled that out because it tends to rate places like stadiums (which likely have large numbers of checkins) higher than a museum or landmark which is of more interest to a tourist.

Are there other options I should be looking at or better ways to use the above two APIs?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this google places API url. You will get the point of interest/Attraction/Tourists places in (For Eg:) **New York City**. You have to use the **CITY NAME** with the keyword **Point Of Interest**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY
```

These result have all the contents that you have asked for like categorization (Museum, Landmark, ...) a picture, a two - three line summary about it and rating.

[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867833/3623027)